# Disconnect Local Clock from Domain Controller Clock

Tags: windows, active-directory, ntp, time

How can I disconnect my workstation clock from the domain controller?

In other words, I do *not* want them synchronized.

Comment: Why not?  It sounds like you might be trying to solve some other problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop the windows time service, this will prevent the computer from being able to sync with the domain controller. You can disable this service if you need it to not sync over a number of reboots.

I would warn against doing this for a long period of time however, as if your local clock gets out of sync with the domain controllers time, you will have problems logging on.

Comment: If your local clock is +/- 5 mins kerberos will not be happy and you won't be able to log in.